# Delphi 7 Application best practices / must haves

Tags: delphi

We have an application made in Delphi 7 that has been evolving for over a decade.  We are currently migrating to XE2, but that will take a bit of time.

I recently discovered FastMM replacement memory manager.  After reading this seems like a no-brainer step for any application in Delphi 7 (or earlier?). Sadly, we are just discovering it; I suppose to do lack of knowledge or exposure.

My question is are there other additions like FastMM that are also no brainers when creating an application with Delphi 7, other small tweaks, components, tools or units like this one that most people would agree should be added to virtually any application for Delphi 7.  I know many things have come to light over the years or components come into existence that we may not be aware of.  Googling for this information gives most out of date results.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Have a look in documentation, [What's new](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/What%27s_New).

Comment: Your question is really too broad to get any really useful answers. More contextual information is required, like problem domains, scale of projects, budget etc. You need to narrow down your question to specific problem domains and contexts, like "I need a good logging tool for Delphi. What are the options?". etc.

Comment: The other no-brainer is madExcept or EurekaLog. I happen to use the former and heartily recommend it. I've never heard a bad word said against EurekaLog either.

Comment: Glad you're migrating! That's the most important step. If you have questions while migrating, specific ones, please ask them and we'll all try our best to answer.  Welcome to stack overflow. I voted to close your question not because it's not a good question but because it is not precisely and directly answerable, it's a discussion topic.  This would be a great question to post on Embarcadero's forums. Good luck.

Comment: This might fit on Programmers.stackexchange, but then, they seem to be "closing everything subjective" over there, these days too.

Comment: @WarrenP: The Programmer's FAQ reads almost identically to the SO one in regards to subjective or discussion questions. So do most of the other SE sites I've seen.

Answer (score 4):

This kind of question (and answering it) has the risk of raising lots of discussion, but the information you ask for is valuable for others, so here is my answer:

- use development productivity tools like [ModelMaker Code Explorer](http://www.modelmakertools.com/code-explorer/index.html), [Castallia](http://www.twodesk.com/castalia/), [cnPack IDE Wizards](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cnwizards/) or [GExperts](http://www.gexperts.org/) (this `or` is not exclusive)
- use [FastMM4](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fastmm/)
- use an exception catcher like [madExcept](http://madshi.net/madExceptDescription.htm)
- use a logging tool like [CodeSite](http://www.raize.com/devtools/codesite/Default.asp) or [Eurekalog](http://www.eurekalog.com/)
- use a GUI control suite like those from DevExpress, [Raize](http://www.raize.com/devtools/rzcomps/), [JVCL](http://jvcl.delphi-jedi.org/), etc (there are way more)
- use a base library like [JCL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jcl/)

There is far more, maybe we should make this a community wiki.

From an upgrade perspective, my experience is that you best can upgrade all your 3rd party libraries to the latest version one by one, and then finally upgrade Delphi. That makes transitioning a multi-step process, which is easier to manage.

Comment: Maybe this could be moved to Programmers.SE?  Such wiki questions are valuable, but not valued here on StackOverflow. (I voted to close because I understand that FAQ-compliance matters here more than anything else, but I actually like this question.)

Comment: Well I guess we were not doing that bad, if that is a relatively complete list.  We already use cnPack (and have used GExperts and Castalia), we use madExcept, we do not use any logging, we have JVCL/JCL and some other component suites.   What I was afraid of was that there were more things like FastMM that maybe are not visual but are must haves for delphi applications.

Comment: It totally depends on what you do with Delphi. Let us know what kind of applications you create, and we can help you further: just ask a specific question.